# I am having some issue and i can't figure it out

Tags: php, if-statement, filter, conditional-statements

I am trying to filter the salary payment list between the limite year and month.Here is my code

```
if( ($selY < $join_y) || ($selM < $join_m) ){
   show staff_name;
}
```

$selY and $selM are the variable that are coming form the input box that user typed.
$joinY and $joinM are the variable that is the join year and join month of each staff.

i've got two salary for instance.

```
Staff name  join_year join_month
1      Sanny  2000      july 
2      John   2012      November
```

When the user type 2000 and September(09) i want to show Only "Sanny"
If the user type 2012 and December(12) i am going to show Both Sanny and John
But if  the user type 2012 and april(04) i want to show "Sanny".

I use the above condition statement to filter this out.but my code  didn't work at all.Sorry for my bad english.Thanks very much and looking forward the solutions ...

Comment: It will help if you add a language tag to this (is it perl?) and say what went wrong rather than "it didn't work at all"

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the user if either;

- The selected year is greater than the join year
  or
- the selected year is the same as the join year, and the selected month is greater than the join month.

That would mean;

```
if ( ($selY > $join_y) || ($selY == $join_y && $selM > $join_m) ) {
   show staff_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but it didn't solve my prob.if i choose 2012 and September it show Sanny only

Comment: @user2519372 Hm, John is Nov 2012, so why would he show up when you select Sep 2012 when he had not yet joined?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake . i choose Dec 2012 and only show up Sanny not John